# ok method in PlayFramework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a question about ok method in PlayFramework.
I am using play2.2.1.
Let's say no view's file and no model's file and only controller's file.
And the code is like this:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.data.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

import java.util.*;
import models.*;

import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;

public class Application extends Controller {
    //Action correspoinding to root
    public static Result index() {
        return ok("This is test.");
    }
}
```

when I run the play application, I can get very simple page just displaying "This is test.".
I know a basic mechanism about how PlayFramework displays any pages.
In very straightforward situation, a user has a certain page's access and by following information "routes" shows a specific method is chosen and within the method, basically ok method renders Result instance.
After that, the contents of the instance is passed by from controller to view and view is used in displaying.
However, in this case, there is no view.
So, how does the framework display this very simple page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're assuming that the webbrowser needs html to display something. It doesn't, it can also display plain strings, which is what you see here. A fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fLxhyjtu/

You could also try:

```
ok("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
```

after all, html is just a string too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.      Once again, there is no View file.   And when PlayApplication has any view file, the view file will receive the content of Result instance from controller's class which is of course corresponding with the view file. .   And then the view can display something.     I already recognize what you said, but I am sorry that I can't your meaning well, I don't understand my question has something to do with the fact that browser can display plain text files.

Comment: A certain guiding book probably says that the ok method take something as the argument and then playapplication can display something. At the same time, the ok method can take a html text. So, if the ok method can take a html file and read this and then convert the html text, we can prepare html files beforehand. Under the way of thinking, the concept of template came out. To sum up, it is special that we have any view file, and everything is understood by above explanation I wrote here. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Play's controllers have multiple overridden versions of the `ok()` method. And of course of others like `badRequest`, `notFound`, etc.

You can start looking at the different methods here: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html#ok()

There is one having `String` parameter, having a `JsonNode` parameter, having a `byte[]` parameter and so on.

Notice that `play.mvc.Controller` extends `play.mvc.Results` and this is actually where the methods are defined.

Your browser is then capable of displaying either HTML or plain text or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so how is the mechanism?        I understand the ok method can take a variety of parameter as the argument and browser can display a plain text as well as html files.

Comment: A certain guiding book probably says that the ok method take something as the argument and then playapplication can display something.  At the same time, the ok method can take a html text. So, if the ok method can take a html file and read this and then convert the html text, we can prepare html files beforehand.    Under the way of thinking, the concept of template came out.     To sum up, it is special that we have any view file, and everything is understood by above explanation I wrote here.   Am I right?